# Wiregurard override wg0.conf

Tags: debian, wireguard

I have successfully installed Wireguard on Debian Buster. Now I wanted to configure IPv6 afterwards. I have done that. But the settings inside the `[Peer]`-Section of `wg0.conf` do not seem to be persistent.

```
systemctl stop wg-quick@wg0.service
nano /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
```

Result:

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32, xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::2/72
```

After saving and restarting the service `systemctl start wg-quick@wg0.service` the `wg0.conf` looks fine.

When I restart the VM or the Service again, all my additional settings are lost.

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = xxxxx
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32
```

Any idea?

Thats how my `wg0.conf` should look like

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.200.200.1/24
Address = xxxx:xxx:xx:xxx::1/72
DNS = 10.200.200.1
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROU$
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTR$
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = xxx

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32, xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::2/72

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.3/32, xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::3/72

[Peer]
PublicKey = xxx
AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.4/32, xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::4/72
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved the issue. **The magic trick:** always stop the Interface with `wg-quick down wg0` before editing the `wg0.conf` File. `systemctl stop wg-quick@wg0.service` **will override** the `wg0.conf` File after the next start.

Comment: For anyone like me wondering "Why???" the answer is that SaveConfig is on by default, documented here: https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8.en.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Ubuntu server 22.04LTS. I noticed that the wg0.conf was read (toggling "SaveConfig = true" to false and vice versa was followed) and I even could add a new peer. But any changes to existing peers were ignored.
In my case the adding of an allowed IPv6 IP obviously caused a parsing error without any error report. At the beginning I added the IPv6 address like this

> AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32, xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::2/64

and it did not work. Then I accidently I forgot the segment descriptor /64

> AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/32, **xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::2**

and it works! wg0 reports

AllowedIPs = 10.200.200.2/3 xxx:xxxx:xx:xxx:100::2/128

I can not tell you the exact reason of the behaviour, but for me the problem is solved.